# Как решить проблему с прыгающим изображением?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста. При загрузке страницы прыгает изображение (выпрыгивает из блока "галереи" потом возвращается на место), не очень аккуратно смотрится, как можно решить эту проблему?
[image: Скрин]

```html
<div id="gallery" class="text-center">
                  <ul id="lightgallery">
                        <li data-thumb="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_6_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" data-src="/uploads/images/tb/1376_f_6_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg">
               <img class="back" alt="Готовый дом в Супсехе" src="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_6_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" />
               <img class="front" alt="Готовый дом в Супсехе" src="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_6_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" /> 
            </li>
                        <li data-thumb="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_7_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" data-src="/uploads/images/tb/1376_f_7_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg">
               <img class="back" alt="Готовый дом в Супсехе" src="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_7_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" />
               <img class="front" alt="Готовый дом в Супсехе" src="/uploads/images/ts/1376_f_7_gotovyi-dom-v-supsehe.jpg" /> 
            </li>
                     </ul>
               </div>
<link href="/templates/easy/css/style-mes.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/templates/easy/gallery/lightslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/templates/easy/gallery/lightslider.js"></script>
<link href="/templates/easy/gallery/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/templates/easy/gallery/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#lightgallery").lightSlider({gallery:!0,item:1,thumbItem:9,currentPagerPosition:"left",onSliderLoad:function(a){a.lightGallery({selector:"#lightgallery .lslide"})}})});</script>
<link href="/templates/easy/css/voting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/votingfiles/voting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script>function go(addr) {window.open(addr,"MyWin", "scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,width=700,height=668");}</script><!--body2-->
```

Comment: попробуйте подать код без smarty. Так как он выглядит на сайте

Comment: @klifort Подправил

Comment: все равно ничего не видно так как вы пытаетесь подключить стили и файлы JS из своего сайте. Нажмите "Выполнить код"

Comment: К сожалению, у меня не хватает знаний чтобы сэмулировать проблему тут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - вот стоит почитать, по другому тяжело будет помочь